# Aws Cognito Service Placement Advice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have moved my microservices behind **AWS Api Gateway** and have secured it with **oAuth 2.0** using **AWS Cognito**, As per my implementation the client first have to call the cognito url to get the access token, then they will call Api Gateway with the access token to reach till the desired service. 
My question is that, should i also move cognito service behind Api Gateway or should i leave it as is, what would be better both in terms of billing and security. Expert Advice required.

This is my first implementation with Aws so please bear with me if the questions sounds stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a blogpost where they explore a Cognito setup combined with API Gateway. You can read it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/). This image is an excerpt of that blogpost:

[image]

As you can see, the Cognito infrastructure is not placed *behind* the API Gateway, but rather in front of it. A good reason for this is to not incur charges for API Gateway when your users are not even able to pass through cognito.

**But**, this is not a rule. API Gateway offers advantages that could make your life easier, as the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330743/shoaib-ahmed) has pointed out. For instance, API Gateway can impose rate limiting, next to other features.

Comment: Your argument is valid that it will save cost, but if i keep it outside of gateway i have to expose the cognito url to the client directly (https:/service-api.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token) wouldn't that be a security issue ?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if it is a security issue. What would be the difference between an attacker trying to abuse your OAuth2 endpoint directly, or via API Gateway?

Comment: With API Gateway i can place validations like rate limiting which i don't think are possible with cognito, plus if i want to change Cognito with any other service in future, the api gateway url will remain same for the clients, and the process would remain seamless at clients end, what do you say ?

Comment: Those are all valid points. I think it boils down to personal preference. But the remarks you make have convinced me that it is a better idea to hide it behind API Gateway, *if* you are willing to pay the charges (which are really not *that* high)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback it was really helpful, i will sit back and finalize what should be done based on my preferences :)

Comment: Good to hear! Good luck!

Comment: i have published the article, please have a look
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/configuring-micro-services-behind-aws-api-gateway-oauth-ahmed-khan/

Comment: Cool, I've read it! You decided to not hide it behind API Gateway after all?

Comment: Yes, i finally decided to keep it separately .

Comment: I see, I think that's a good decision. Will you accept the answer or will you leave the question unanswered?

Comment: let's wait for a few more answers, may be we get a better explanation and reasoning than ours :)